# Tcpdump capturing Ethernet frames

Tags: tcpdump

How can i use tcpdump to capture Ethernet frames and display any frame sent or received by the local PC with one of the UDP, ARP, and ICMP protocols.

I was trying this command:

sudo tcpdump -e udp or arp or  icmp

but, i thinks it's wrong.

Comment: I do not know, but the comand is that okay?

Comment: that command works fine for me

Comment: oh ok, instead of using "-e" can i use "-x", it's the same thing, right? both of them get the ethernet header?

Comment: All of them get the ethernet header, "-e" just displays it. You can combine "-xe" `-e     Print the link-level header on each dump line.`

Comment: So why do you think it's wrong?  Have you tried it?  If so, what did it do that wasn't what you wanted it to do?  If you *haven't* tried it, try it and see what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Do use `tcpdump -e`. Here's an example of the output:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:36:02.408697 02:42:ac:11:00:02 (oui Unknown) > 02:42:ac:11:00:03 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: client.60546 > yahoo.com.80: Flags [S], seq 1673384407, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2181456358 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

In this example, you can see frame fields such as the MAC addresses (e.g. `02:42:ac:11:00:03`) and the frame type (e.g. `ethertype IPv4 0x0800`).

From the manpage:

> If the '-e' option is given, the link level header is printed out.  On Ethernets, the source and destination addresses, protocol, and packet length are printed.
>
> On  FDDI  networks, the  '-e' option causes tcpdump to print the `frame control' field,  the source and destination addresses, and the packet length.  (The `frame control' field governs the interpretation of the rest of the packet.  Normal packets (such as those containing IP datagrams) are `async' packets, with a priority  value  between  0  and  7; for example, `async4'.  Such packets are assumed to contain an 802.2 Logical Link Control (LLC) packet; the LLC header is printed if it is not an ISO datagram or a so-called SNAP packet.
>
> On Token Ring networks, the '-e' option causes tcpdump to print the `access control' and `frame control' fields, the source  and  destination  addresses,  and  the  packet length.   As  on FDDI networks, packets are assumed to contain an LLC packet.  Regardless of whether the '-e' option is specified or not, the source routing information is printed for source-routed packets.
>
> On 802.11 networks, the '-e' option causes tcpdump to print the `frame control' fields, all of the addresses in the 802.11 header, and the packet length.  As on FDDI  net‐works, packets are assumed to contain an LLC packet.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an example, how you can capture enthernet frame from your localhost.
sudo tcpdump -i lo -nnvvvexxXXKS -s0
for capturing the frame we used "exxXX"

Answer (score -4):

First of all, you are interested in *packets*, not frames. Frames are a layer below packets and only chip manufacturers are concerned with them. Second, you must specify your interface with the `-i` switch or promiscuous mode won't be even activated for you to see everything - if that's what you want.

Comment: so the command should be : sudo tcpdump -i -e udp or arp or  icmp?

Comment: More like: `sudo tcpdump -e -n -i eth0 ether proto arp`. The whole `ether proto arp` is a shared syntax from PCAP.

Comment: this works without the -i switch if its the only interface on the host

Comment: The `-i` switch is only necessary if the default interface that tcpdump chooses isn't the interface on which you want to capture; if, for example, you have only `eth0` and `lo`, tcpdump will default to `eth0`, so you don't need to specify `-i eth0`.

Comment: Does, or is there an option to capture all ethernet frames, such as ethernet pause frames?